# Why is there an empty space being added to my nav-element?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I tried to follow this explanation for building a dropdown menu using only HTML and CSS:

[Line25.com - How to create a purse CSS dropdown menu](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

I tried to reduce the given example to find out which parts are absolutely necessary, leaving out the purely visual declarations (background colors, rounded corners and so on).

That's how I came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 24px;
        }
        nav {
            background-color: green;
        }
        nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-table;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
        nav ul:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        nav ul li {
            float: left;
        }
        nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 25px 40px;
        }
        nav ul ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            background-color: orange;
            padding: 0;
        }
        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none;
            position: relative;
        }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="." target="">ITEM1</a></li>
            <li><a href="." target="">ITEM2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="." target="">SUBITEM1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="." target="">SUBITEM2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="." target="">ITEM3</a></li>
            <li><a href="." target="">ITEM4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look at this using Chrome or Firefox, there is a small empty space at the bottom of the nav-element. The nav-element is exactly seven pixels higher than the ul-element directly inside of it. This also leads to the dropdown part of the navigation bar being displayed seven pixels too far up.

I can't figure out which part of the left out (or the left in) CSS is responsible for this gap. Can someone help me with this? I would like the top of the dropdown part to be in line with the bottom of the navigation bar. And I would like to reach that goal by understanding where those seven pixels are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: top; /*add this line*/
}
```

Add that line to that CSS block. This is because your `ul` has been set to some form of `inline`. The spacing occurs because the default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`, which causes the element to sit on the same line on which text sits. This line has spacing below it for letters which descend below it (`y` for example). The following image may help you to visualise this baseline:

[image: Visualisation of the text's baseline].

Comment: This answer and the one by ntl both work, but this one explains where the extra pixels come from. That's why I have marked this one as the correct answer. Please check out the answer by ntl as well for a more consistent approach to my poorly coded example.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more solution:

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 24px;
        }
        nav {
            background-color: green;
        }
        nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-table;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
        nav ul:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        nav ul li {
            display: table-cell;
        }
        nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 25px 40px;
        }
        nav ul ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            background-color: orange;
            padding: 0;
        }
        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
        nav ul ul li {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
        }
```

Changes:

```
  nav ul li {
            display: table-cell;
        }

  nav ul ul li {
            display: block;
```

I prefer this one, because you will keep your aproach consistent. If you use inline-table for your ul's, it better to use table-cell for li's, to keep everything in same fashion and don't mix inline-table and floats.